# Diff tool with nice output like kdiff3

Tags: colors, diff

I like kdiff3 very much due to the way it displays the result. It can compare more than two versions of a file or directory and displays the differences in columns:

- For directories, it displays their tree structure and it's easily recognizable which file exists/is modified where
- For files, it shows one column per file with the full text, highlighting the differences using various colors indicating the type of difference.

Here is a screenshot for those who don't know it:
[image]

Often, I would like to give away this nice output, but unfortunately, KDiff3 does not support to save/print its output.

The simple output of the command line tool `diff` is a bit... puristic, with option `-y` I get at least a two-column-output, but also the output is not so nice.

`colordiff` seems not to be what I'm looking for.

Is there any other tool that can produce an output like this and save it to html/pdf/whatever?

---

Edit:
I'm looking for a tool, which

- compares files and entire directories
- three or more versions
- generates side-by-side view of entire files
- colors the differences to make them more visible
- **allows to save this to a common format like HTML or PDF**

The last point is the most important. Something like a screenshot would do the job, but usually, the files are too large for the screen, and I did not find a tool for linux yet, which can capture an entire window.

Comment: I have been using screenshots for this, assuming the changes would fit on my 3840x1200 or 1200x1920 pixels. Neither `meld`, `diffuse` nor `meld` that I regularly use can do this. `diffuse` is in Python so you might be able to put the functionality in yourself without to much problems.

Answer (score 2):

[coderev](https://github.com/ymattw/coderev) can do that.

Its top-level tool (`coderev.sh`) is set up to work with CVS or SVN repositories, but it's just a driver for `codediff.py`, which does all the actual work.

To get side-by-side views, I think you have to do a directory diff, rather than a file diff. When I tried a single-file diff, it gave me an inline view of the diffs instead. Of course, that may be fine for your purposes as well.

There is [an online demo](http://ymattw.github.io/coderev/demo/index.html).

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks for now! Let me try it out!